# Apache Reverse Proxy | Wildcard directory rerouting (.htaccess)

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, reverse-proxy, directory

How would it be possible to have a wildcard directory proxy?

I have gotten the basics but the issue is, it gives out the directory which I'm in, my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(u|api|fonts|images|css|js) [NC]

# No directory

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png|txt|mp4|mp3|json|js|zip|bmp|tiff|webp|webm|raw|psd|jpeg|jpe|wav)(.*) http://127.0.0.1:9000/owoapi/$1.$2$3?%{QUERY_STRING} [proxy]

# One Directory
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)\.
(jpg|gif|png|txt|mp4|mp3|json|js|zip|bmp|tiff|webp|webm|raw|psd|jpeg|jpe|wav)
(.*) http://127.0.0.1:9000/owoapi/$1.$2$3?%{QUERY_STRING} [proxy]
```

When visiting `domain.tld/image.png`, it works just fine.

When visiting `domain.tld/test/image.png`, it 404's due to the fact that it includes /test/ in the proxied URL, how would I go about fixing that?

Edit: What I'm trying to achieve is to not include the preceding URL and make it act like it's being accessed via `domain.tld/image.png` instead of `domain.tld/test/image.png`

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. What _should_ happen when you request `example.com/test/image.png`? Do you simply want to ignore the preceding URL-path?

Comment: Yeah @user82217, the preceding URL path should be ignored

Comment: I'm curious, what are you trying to capture with the trailing `(.*)` on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_?

Comment: @user82217 I run a service which serves files from a backend, I have hardcoded filetypes to be scanned as to what is served and what is not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> # One Directory
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)\. ......
> ```

Simply remove the braces around the first captured pattern (since you don't need to capture this group):

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)\. ......
```

Note that this only handles one subdirectory segment (which I assume is the intention).

Alternatively, you could have changed the backreferences from `$1.$2$3` to `$2.$3$4`.

**UPDATE#1:** In addition to the above, you will need to change the preceding "No directory" block so that it indeed matches *no* directory. As it stands, it is matching the entire URL-path (ie. directories) and so the second rule is not even being processed...

> ```
> # No directory
> RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|gif| ......
> ```

Change to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.(jpg|gif| ......
```

**UPDATE#2:** To handle (and ignore) any level of subdirectory, simply remove the start of string anchor (ie. `^`) from the above `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.(jpg|gif| ......
```

Comment: I just tried your first suggestion, the outcome of it is: https://ratelimited.me/72e033.png | Same for the second suggestion (Which I tried before)

Comment: Ah, your first directive is catching everything. I've updated my answer.

Comment: By the way, how would I be able to add more directories if needed?

Comment: To handle any level of subdirectory you can just remove the `^` prefix on the  _updated_ regex on your first rule - I've updated my answer. However, do you need to explicitly restrict this to certain directory levels?

Comment: I do not need any kind of restriction :)